# Community Standards for Protecting Questions

Tags: discussion

I haven't seen any meta-discussion on protecting questions, and I don't see this privilege used very often. When do people feel it is appropriate to protect a question?

Answer (score 4):

I protect questions when:

1. They are old (1 year or more)
2. They have multiple (often 10 or more) answers
3. Several of those answers have high answer scores, and one is accepted
4. The delete log shows the question has a history of attracting low-quality answers from new users

In my experience, #4 most often occurs for questions about Nazis and the Confederacy--two topics on which non-historians can have strong opinions. Topic influences my decisions at the margins, but 1-4 are the most important.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't understand how some questions become spam magnets, like this one: http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/10323/how-did-germany-rebuild-so-quickly-after-world-war-i

Comment: "unemployment" + "economy" + "loan" + "welfare" combined with 7k views (because of "Hitler" + "Jews" + "ww2"?) make it good start to find somebody who can't manage to live in modern economy. This is a deadly mixture of kewords, which reached critical mass and exploded